# How to make one node communicate with multiple nodes?

Tags: omnet++, cc

I am trying to make my nodes communicate among themselves without changing any data in the message.
Like node one and two echos tictocMsg with themselves node two and three echos the different message in this case rndMsg.
How ever this did not work with me.

```
simple Txc1
{
    gates:
        input in1;
        input in2;
        output out1;
        output out2;
}

//
// Two instances (tic and toc) of Txc1 connected both ways.
// Tic and toc will pass messages to one another.
//
network Tictoc1
{
    @display("bgb=628,433");
    submodules:
        tic: Txc1 {
            @display("p=264,321");
        }
        toc: Txc1;
        rnd: Txc1 {
            @display("p=474,100");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        toc.out1 --> tic.in1;
        tic.out1 --> toc.in1;
        toc.out2 --> rnd.in1;
        rnd.out1 --> toc.in2;
}
```

[image]

I want to make toc node to send tictocMsg to tic node only and rndMsg to rnd node only

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * Derive the Txc1 class from cSimpleModule. In the Tictoc1 network,
 * both the `tic' and `toc' modules are Txc1 objects, created by OMNeT++
 * at the beginning of the simulation.
 */
class Txc1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Txc1);

void Txc1::initialize()
{
    // Initialize is called at the beginning of the simulation.
    // To bootstrap the tic-toc-tic-toc process, one of the modules needs
    // to send the first message. Let this be `tic'.

    // Am I Tic or Toc?
    if (strcmp("tic", getName()) == 0) {
        // create and send first message on gate "out". "tictocMsg" is an
        // arbitrary string which will be the name of the message object.
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");
        send(msg, "out1");
    }
    if (strcmp("rnd",getName())==0){
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("rndMsg");
                send(msg, "out1");
    }
}

void Txc1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // The handleMessage() method is called whenever a message arrives
    // at the module. Here, we just send it to the other module, through
    // gate `out'. Because both `tic' and `toc' does the same, the message
    send(msg,"out1");
    // send out the message
}
```

I have tried to change it to

```
send(msg,"in1","out1") ;
send(msg,"in2","out2") ;
```

tried

```
send(msg,out1)}
else{
send(msg,out2)}
}
```

by far both did not work for me is there any way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

The node in the middle (i.e. `toc`) has to somehow recognize received messages. For example it may check the name of the message. Let's assume that:

- `toc` after receiving message with the name `tictocMsg` sends it to `tic`,
- `toc` after receiving message with the name `rndMsg` sends it to `rnd`,
- `tic` and `rnd` after receiving message send it to `toc`.

The following piece of code performs the above rules:

```
void Txc1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
  if (isName("toc")) {
    if (msg->isName("tictocMsg")) {
        send(msg,"out1");
    } else if (msg->isName("rndMsg")) {
        send(msg,"out2");
    }
  } else {
    // other nodes just sends this message back
    send(msg,"out1");
  }
}
```